# Prevent redirecting scripts on loading through jquery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I am having a page on which I am loading contents of another url (in the same domain) say like

```
$("#preloaded_main_page").load('main/');
```

Now due to some scripts in the page, the current page is getting redirected to domain.com/main which I want to prevent. All I want to do is to just load the content & the images. Note that the div in which I am loading is hidden. I just want some elements to be cached.

I tried:

```
$("#preloaded_main_page").unbind().load('main/', function() {
  $("#preloaded_main_page *").unbind('click');
  $(window).unbind('hashchange');
});
```

but to no effect. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how doing a load will execute a location change. I have a few steps you can follow in order to debug what is happening. Hope it helps.

1. Comment out your code and make sure that no other part of the site is doing the redirect.
2. Make sure that there is no script tag that runs on the main page that your trying to load. Why? Because script tags on text/html MIME type is evaluated and executed.
3. Try using a standard $.ajax over the .load method:

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'text/html',
                 cache: false,
                 url: '/main',
                 success: function (data) {
                          if(data != '') $('#preloaded_main_page').html(data);
                 }
        });
   });

Code tag doesn't seem to work. So you need to make line-breaks and such your self :)

-

If there is any other scripts on the page that redirects you'll need to specify a global variable making sure that it will only redirect after the content is loaded and not while. If that is the case.